# How to set figure size in yellowbrick plots?

Tags: python, yellowbrick

So I've just recently started to discover the power of `yellowbrick` library (thanks!) but is there a way I could set a figure size for the inline plots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thanks for giving Yellowbrick (scikit-yb.org) a try!  Be sure to follow us on Twitter @scikit-yb and star us on GitHib (https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick).

To address your question (which is addressed along with other plot customization and other questions in our FAQs in the docs: https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/faq.html):
You can change the size of a plot by passing in the desired dimensions in pixels on instantiation of the visualizer (note the below is an example for RadViz but the size param works across Yellowbrick):

## Import the visualizer

```py
from yellowbrick.features import RadViz
```

## Instantiate the visualizer using the `size` param

```py
visualizer = RadViz(
    classes=classes, features=features, size=(1080, 720))
```

Thanks for the question, check out our docs, work through the tutorials in the docs and go forth and conquer!  Stay in touch with us on Twitter!
Thanks,
Team Yellowbrick